# How to change meta to option (macOS) in zle emacs keymap?

Tags: zsh, macos, zle

Since I use both bash and zsh, I'd like to learn the zle's emacs keymap (since this is the default in bash). My problem is that macOS's option key does not work with the meta shortcuts (like M-. for yanking the last argument from the last command). Is there a way to set the option key to meta?

Comment: This isn't up to zsh, it's up to the terminal emulator. E.g. Terminal, iTerm2, …

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the <kbd>Meta</kbd> character is changed to <kbd>Esc</kbd> and since I use the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> keys, I've mapped the real <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to the <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It's one key away, but that's ok.